# Difference between Google's API Gateway and Cloud Endpoints

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-api-gateway

Recently I checked that Google release an [API Gateway](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs) product, but I don't get what is the difference between the already created [Cloud Endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/), both of them seems to be very similar.

Is `API Gateway` a newer version of `Cloud Endpoints`?. Or is it something different?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you share the google API gateway page?, AFAIK google offers 2 API gateways `apigee` and GCP `Cloud Endpoints`

Comment: @J.A.Hernández I added it to the question

Answer (score 24, accepted):

API Gateway is a new GCP service, [just announced today](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/serverless/google-cloud-api-gateway-is-now-available-in-public-beta).

From what can be understood, it is an improved version of Cloud Endpoints. API Gateway can manage APIs for multiple backends including Cloud Functions, Cloud Run, App Engine, Compute Engine and Google Kubernetes Engine.

***The main difference*** under the hood it is that API gateway doesn't rely over Cloud run making more user friendly, fast and clean the implementation.

Both products, API gateway and Cloud endpoints support same Open API implementation.

Comment: Another difference of note is that the beta release of API Gateway doesn't yet support custom domains. You can set up your own load balancer to redirect traffic to a custom domain, but not as easy as with Cloud Endpoints. Other than this quirk, i prefer API Gateway's simplicity.

Comment: Does API Gateway support something like Cloud Endpoints Portal? Or I should build my own swagger document?

Comment: I understand that the GCP API Gateway doesn't have a developer portal at the moment

Comment: does this sentence make sense in english? "The main difference under the hood it is that API gateway doesn't rely over Cloud run making more user friendly, fast and clean the implementation."

Answer (score 1):

API Gateway and Cloud Endpoints are quite similar, both in features and pricing ([API Gateway](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/pricing), [Cloud Endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/pricing)).

API Gateway is managed, but Cloud Endpoints is not. For Cloud Endpoints, you need to [deploy the ESPv2 proxy yourself](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/deploy-api-backend#compute-engine). Also, API Gateway cannot have a non-serverless backends like GCE or GKE as upstream targets, and it’s not available in all GCP regions