# Difference between Google Cloud Endpoints vs. Google API Gateway

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-api-gateway

I recently stumbled over two products of GCP and am unsure how to differ them. The product descriptions of both always sound like the ultimate solution but I can't find a real difference between them.

https://cloud.google.com/endpoints vs. https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway

Answer (score 0):

The API Gateway is very new product as it still in BETA. Seems to be fully managed which means that most of management job should be delivered by Google technology.

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63795473/difference-between-googles-api-gateway-and-cloud-endpoints) that explain this quite well.

Generally, if care about support at the moment you should use Endpoints which are fully featured product.

Comment: API Gateway is now in GA